# Google Drive API V3 -Simple create a folder in a folder issue

Tags: rest, api

Here is my simple REST call to create a folder IN A SUBFOLDER.

It keeps putting it in the ROOT FOLDER.

POST https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
-H "Authorization : Bearer {token}"

```
{
    "name": "myfirstfolder",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
    "parents": [
                   {
                      "id": "0B91rpF8r40YJaHJpSXpvWmxPVkk" 
                   }
               ]
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It is putting it in the root folder every time.

Answer (score 6):

How about following modification?

**Before :**

```
{
    "name": "myfirstfolder",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
    "parents": [
                   {
                      "id": "0B91rpF8r40YJaHJpSXpvWmxPVkk" 
                   }
               ]
}
```

**After :**

```
{
    "name": "myfirstfolder",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
    "parents": ["0B91rpF8r40YJaHJpSXpvWmxPVkk"]
}
```

If this doesn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: Works perfectly fine!